# AspectJ Load Time weaving working in unit tests but NOT at runtime in spring boot (maven) application

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, load-time-weaving

> We have JAVA micro service which constitutes lot of logging. The logging as of now is inconsistent. As a part of improvement, I plan to have an aspect so as we log/append certain data points against each info/error/warn being logged. The data points will be picked form current thread context. I’m sharing the code.
>   Problem: The load time weaving works with unit tests, but when the application is run, nothing happens. That means the weaving is not taking place. The application use tomcat hosting.

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>a.b.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-b-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>a-b-processor</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jose4j.version>0.6.2</jose4j.version>
        <spring.jms.version>4.3.11.RELEASE</spring.jms.version>
        <org.json.version>20180130</org.json.version>
        <aspectjrt.version>1.9.1</aspectjrt.version>
        <aspectjweaver.version>1.9.1</aspectjweaver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.jms.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\${aspectj.version}\aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                        </argLine>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/aspect/marker/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/controller/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/enums/*.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <preparationGoals>clean verify replacer:replace docker:build -DdockerRepo=greenbuild-repo
                        -DpushImageTag scm:checkin -Dmessage="[maven-release-plugin] prepare release" promote:artifacts
                        deploy:deploy
                    </preparationGoals>
                    <completionGoals>clean verify replacer:replace scm:checkin -Dmessage="[maven-release-plugin] prepare
                        for next development iteration"
                    </completionGoals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jxr-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${java.version}</targetJdk>
                    <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:http://github.com/prr.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>1.0.1</tag>
    </scm>
</project>
```

> aspectj aop.xml

```
    <aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.e.s.aspect.uniformLoggerAspect"/>
        <weaver options="-debug -showWeaveInfo">
            <include call="* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..)"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

> uniformLoggerAspect

```
    import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils;

@Aspect
public class uniformLoggerAspect {

    @Around("uniformLoggerPointCut()")
    public Object formatMessageLog(final Object msg, final Throwable exception
            , final ProceedingJoinPoint invocation
            , final JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart callerContext) throws Throwable {

        return formatLogAndProceed(msg, exception, invocation, callerContext);
    }

    private Object formatLogAndProceed(final Object msg, final Throwable exception
            , final ProceedingJoinPoint invocation
            , final JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart callerContext
    ) throws Throwable {

        final Object[] arguments = (Object[]) invocation.getArgs();

        Context context = Context.getCurrentContext();

        if (context != null) {
            arguments[0] = String.format("Cor Id:[%s], PId[%s], IId:[%s], PkId:[%s] LId:[{%s}] [%s]", context.getCorId(), "123", "xyz", context.getPkId(), context.getLId(), arguments[0]);

        return invocation.proceed(arguments);
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..))")
    public void uniformLoggerPointCut() {
    }
}
```